# Excel Web Query Parameters Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-web-query

I'm having troubles adding parameters to a Web Query that reads currency rates.

**Parameter:** date format that updates daily (YEARMONTHDAY) in Cell ("A1") - As ["datums"]

**URL:** http://www.bank.lv/vk/ecb.xml?date=**["datums"]**

**Error - in URL:**
[image]

**Error - in Excel:**
[image]

**Excel - Parameter:**
[image]

Comment: Do you even know how its works? Try open this http://www.bank.lv/vk/ecb.xml?date=20170817

Comment: I have the parameter set to update every day. If I simply type in the date, it won't automatically update.

Comment: Does anyone know how I could solve this issue?